# return row[0] === userId.matches(userId); no devuelve nada

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Usando Google Apps Script he intentado crear una herramienta para buscar productos por nombre a través de un formulario.
Cuando busco algún producto no me muestra nada, entiendo que es porque en el código la parte siguiente:

```
return row[0] === userId.matches(userId);
```

No está bien hecha.
Si dicha parte la modifico a `return row[0] === userId;` me muestra solo los resultados que son exactamente igual a lo introducido en el formulario, pero necesito que me muestre todos los resultados que contienen esa palabra escrita.
La "base de datos" la tengo en un Google Sheet, donde tengo dos columnas: en una de ellas está el nombre y en la otra el nº de stock. Lo que la herramienta debería de hacer es mostrarme todas las filas donde aparezca el campo buscado, independientemente que tenga más texto esa línea del documento.

¿Me podríais por favor ayudar?

Adjunto los códigos de ambos archivos, tanto del formulario como del archivo js:

```js
// Archivo Código.gs

// URL que genera Google Sheet al solicitar link para compartir
var myGoogleSheetURL =
  "OCULTO";

// Nombre de la hoja donde estan nuestros datos
var myGoogleSheetName = "OCULTO";

/**
 * Función de inicialización ( la primera que se ejecuta )
 */
function doGet() {
  // Muestra el HTML
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('formulario');
  return template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

/**
 * Funcion que sera llamada al hacer click en el boton del formulario
 * @param form formulario recibido desde el frontend
 */
function receiveForm(form) {
  // Obtenemos el valor del campo userId
  var userId = form.userId;

  // Llama a la funcion para buscar datos, pasandole el parametro
  return searchData(userId);
}

/**
 * Busca en la hoja de calculos los datos del usuario
 * @param userId ID del usuario que queremos buscar
 */
function searchData(userId) {
  // Obtiene la hoja de calculos
  var sheet = getSpreadSheet(myGoogleSheetURL, myGoogleSheetName);

  // Recorre todas las filas buscando la coincidencia del userID con el valor
  // de la columna 0
  var rowsResult = sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .filter(function (row) {
      return row[0] === userId.matches(userId);
    });

  // Obtiene el resultado
  var firstRow = rowsResult[0];

  // Parsea cada uno de los campos
  var user = {
    id: firstRow[0],
    email: firstRow[1],
    phone: firstRow[2],
  };

  // Serializa el OBJ para enviar la respuesta al frontend
  var result = JSON.stringify(user);
  return result;
}

/**
 * Obtiene una hoja de calculo según la URL y nombre de la hoja especificados
 */
function getSpreadSheet(url, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet;
}
```

```html
<!-- archivo formulario.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>OCULTO</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="OCULTO">
    <base target="_top" />
    <style>
      :root {
        --primary-color: #4caf50;
      }
      body {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
      }
      input {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      input[type="button"] {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 10px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type="button"]:disabled {
        background-color: #dadada;
      }
    </style>
    <title>OCULTO</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Inicio del formulario-->
    <form action="#">
      <input
        id="inputUserId"
        type="text"
        value=""
        name="userId"
        placeholder="PRODUCT NAME"
        onfocus="clearDiv()"
        onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"
      />
      <br />

      <input
        id="btnSend"
        type="button"
        onClick="formSubmit()"
        value="Search"
      />
    </form>
    <!-- Fin del formulario-->

    <!-- div donde se mostraran los resultados -->
    <br>
    <div id="divResponse"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Función que se ejecuta al presionar el boton del formulario
    function formSubmit() {
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "Searching...";

      // Llama a la funcion receiveForm de nuestro script
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .receiveForm(document.forms[0]);

      // Deshabilita los inputs y el btn mientra se hace la llamada
      disableInputs();
    }

    // Función que se ejecuta cuando la busqueda ocurre con exito
    function onSuccess(response) {
      // Parsea la respuesta
      var user = JSON.parse(response);

      // Carga el campo email de la respuesta en el div
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.email;

      // Habilita el campo y boton
      enableInputs();
    }

    // Función que se ejecuta cuando la busqueda ocurre con ERROR
    function onFailure() {
      // Pone mensaje en div
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "Fabric not found";
      enableInputs();
    }

    // Desabilita boton y campo de texto
    function disableInputs() {
      document.getElementById("btnSend").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("inputUserId").disabled = true;
    }

    // Habilita boton y campo de texto
    function enableInputs() {
      document.getElementById("btnSend").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("inputUserId").disabled = false;
    }

    function clearDiv() {
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

---

Me sale el siguiente error en la función searchdata:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at searchData(Código:54:17) .

Dentro de filter puse lo siguiente: `logger.log(typeof row[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres comprobar que un string contiene un cierto substring, la manera más sencilla es usar el método `includes`:

```js
const valores = [
  "saludos","uno","dos", "cuarenta", "texto"
];

console.log(valores.filter(valor => valor.includes("dos")));
```

Con lo que tu código quedaría como:

```
// Recorre todas las filas buscando la coincidencia del userID con el valor
// de la columna 0
var rowsResult = sheet
  .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  .getValues()
  .filter(function (row) {
    return row[0].includes(userId);
  });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, he actualizado el código pero el funcionamiento es el mismo. Es decir, me sigue mostrando solo si el campo buscado es exactamente igual al de la línea del documento google sheet. ¿Igual tengo que modificar también la siguiente parte? 
  // Obtiene el resultado
  var firstRow = rowsResult[0];

  // Parsea cada uno de los campos
  var user = {
    id: firstRow[0],
    email: firstRow[1],
    phone: firstRow[2],
  };

  // Serializa el OBJ para enviar la respuesta al frontend
  var result = JSON.stringify(user);
  return result;

Comment: creo que no debería afectar... si dentro de la función filtro haces un `console.log(typeof row[0])` ¿qué te muestra?

Comment: estoy usando directamente el cloud de Google Script para hacer la aplicación, la cual no tiene consola. Voy a instalarme una consola en local para debuggear a ver si lo consigo sacar el log. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @Isaac Si tiene tiene consola, mas precisamenete tiene donde ver los registros de console.log. Presiona Control + Enter o bien haz clic en el menú Ver > Registros o Ver > Ejecuciones

Comment: Gracias Rubén, me sale el siguiente error en la función searchdata: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at searchData(Código:54:17) . Dentro de filter puse lo siguiente: logger.log(typeof row[0])

Comment: También lo intenté poniendo console.log(typeof row[0]); pero tampoco muestra nada

Comment: @Isaad cuando respondas usa @ antes del nombre de usuario para que se  le envíe una notificación

Comment: Si el filtro descarta todos los elementos, `var firstRow = rowsResult[0];` está asignando `undefined`, por lo que `firstRown[0]` provoca ese error

Comment: Ya conseguí hacerlo funcionar, dentro del filter puse lo siguiente:

    if (row[0].toString().indexOf(userId) === -1) {return false;} else {return true;}

Ahora, solo me muestra la 1º línea que encuentra que contiene el campo buscado.
Entiendo que para que me muestre todas las filas del documento tengo que poner un for por algún lado... gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda ! @PabloLozano

Comment: @Rubén gracias por tu ayuda, en mi comentario anterior puse como lo hice finalmente

Comment: @Isaac si lo que finalmente te ayudó a solucionar no está en esta u otra respuesta, pubica tu solución como respuesta ya que los comentarios tienen poca visibiidad y podrían ser eliminados. Por otro lado, si quieres hacer una pregunta de seguimiento, publicala como una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí hacerlo funcionar, dentro del filter puse lo siguiente:

```
if (row[0].toString().indexOf(userId) === -1) {return false;} else {return true;}
```

Ahora, solo me muestra la 1º línea que encuentra. Entiendo que para que me muestre todas las filas del documento tengo que poner un `for` por algún lado.